# Unbounded sequence with convergent subsequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, recreational-mathematics

I'm just wondering if anyone knows any nice sequences that are unbounded themselves, but have one or more convergent sub-sequences?

Comment: $ a_n = tg(n) $

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the sub-sequence can be finite, then any unbounded sequence will do.

If you want an unbounded sequence with a convergent *infinite* subsequence then take any unbounded sequence with a constant subsequence. E.g. $a_n = n \sin(\frac{\pi n}2)$.

Comment: I never thought of a difference between having a finite or infinite sub sequence, but this is great! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There are plenty.

Take *any* convergent sequence, say $a_n \to a \in \mathbb R$. Then take any unbounded sequence, say $b_n \to \infty$. Then define $$ c_n = \begin{cases} a_n & \text{n even} \\ b_n & \text{n odd.} \end{cases}$$

Then $c_n$ is unbounded, but has a convergent sequence. Notice that you can generalize this: given *any* finite number of convergent sequences, you can make a unbounded sequence with the convergent sequences as subsequences.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an extreme example. Recall that the set of rationals is countably infinite. Enumerate the rationals as $r_1,r_2,r_3, \dots$. Then for **every** real number $x$, there is a subsequence of the sequence $(r_n)$  that has limit $x$.